# Links with users content

Tags: hyperlink

I'm developing a little app in which users can create their own content. Most content is taken from a MYSQL db and images from AWS S3 and brought to the front through regular jquery/php/html. All content a user has created is private and can only be accessed via a login. However, I would like the users to be able to send selected parts of their content to other users and people via links which they can click on and see that selected content. Much like sending a link to a users image on Facebook to someone outside the community.

I have never done this before and have no idea in how to even begin. If anyone could point me in the correct direction it would be highly appreciated. I have searched around about this but don't really know what to search for.

If this is against SO's rules (as it's a general question about a topic and not specialized enough), please let me know and I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this is to have a private bucket in which each user has distinct permissions on his own folder, and be the only one that can access it. This is something you should probably implement on the application level - allowing only the app to access the bucket, and denying every other type of access.

For the public content - you should create a different bucket which will be publicly available for everyone, and move all public content there.

These are my 2 cents, might be better practices in the field, but IMO it's a nice solution which is not to complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll give this a try.

Comment: Cool, if this setup works for you don't forget to mark this answered as the correct one. Good luck.

Comment: Will do! However it will take me a while before I know if it's working :)